# Microsoft Dynamics 365 - workflow process to generate a calendar entry that synchronises with Exchange/Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I'm building a workflow process in Dynamics 365 triggered by changes to a date/time field in the Opportunity entity - this should create (or update) a [Dynamics] Calendar entry for the user to whom this Opportunity is assigned on the date/time in question, which should then automatically synchronise with the user's Exchange calendar because server side Exchange synchronisation is enabled.

I've hit a brick wall with this having tried every option I can think of - the following aspects work but not the end to end solution:

1) The workflow is triggered as expected, and correctly creates the calendar entry in the Dynamics Calendar;

2) If I manually create an entry in the Dynamics Calendar it appears in the user's Exchange calendar, so I know the server side synchronisation is working correctly.

However ... calendar entries created by my workflow are not synching to the Exchange calendar.

I'm convinced I must be missing something extremely obvious but can't fathom it!

Comment: Please turn your edit into an answer to your own question, which is appreciated here for getting solved problems out of the list of unanswered questions. I think it will even award you with a badge.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this now ... Appointments that are created by a workflow process exist in an "open" state (on our Dynamics instances - not sure if this has anything to do with instance settings) whereas manually created Appointments get a status of "scheduled" - it seems the "open" ones don't get synchronised with Exchange.
 
I couldn't find any settings / filters to specifically include open Appointments in the synchronisation, so instead I added a step in my workflow to set the Appointment status to "scheduled", which did the trick.